# CSS display flex does not align divs side by side

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is the html code that I am running

```css
.table-header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-header">

  <div>
    <h3>Balance Forwarded: <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><?php echo $total_Fwd; ?></span></h3>
    <h3>Total Unpaid Balance: <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><?php echo $total_bal; ?></span></h3>
    <h3>Total Interest Charged: <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><?php echo $total_Int; ?></span></h3>
  </div>

  <div>
    <form id="send" action="file.php" target="_blank" method="post">

      <input type="hidden" id="query" name=q uery value="<?php echo $sql; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" id="total_fwd" name=t otal_fwd value="<?php echo $total_Fwd; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" id="total_bal" name=t otal_bal value="<?php echo $total_bal; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" id="total_int" name=t otal_int value="<?php echo $total_Int; ?>">

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Print</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, it does not align the two child divs and looks like this as of the moment:
[image: sample]

I want those two to be side by side using flex, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `align-items: center;` you can also use `gap` to space them.

```css
.table-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-header">

  <div>
    <h3>Balance Forwarded: <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><?php echo $total_Fwd; ?></span></h3>
    <h3>Total Unpaid Balance: <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><?php echo $total_bal; ?></span></h3>
    <h3>Total Interest Charged: <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><?php echo $total_Int; ?></span></h3>
  </div>

  <div>
    <form id="send" action="file.php" target="_blank" method="post">

      <input type="hidden" id="query" name=q uery value="<?php echo $sql; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" id="total_fwd" name=t otal_fwd value="<?php echo $total_Fwd; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" id="total_bal" name=t otal_bal value="<?php echo $total_bal; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" id="total_int" name=t otal_int value="<?php echo $total_Int; ?>">

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Print</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.table-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: 'space-between';
 }
```

Comment: Why the quotes?